# How do I get my percent to work in my Dice program?

Tags: java, arrays, dice, die

```
run:
How many dice do you want to roll: 3

How many sides on die number 1: 5
How many sides on die number 2: 4
How many sides on die number 3: 6

How many times do you want to roll: 65

Results

[3]      1   0.0% 
[4]      2   0.0% 
[5]      4   0.0% 
[6]      6   0.0% 
[7]      4   0.0% 
[8]      12  0.0% 
[9]      12  0.0% 
[10]     8   0.0% 
[11]     12  0.0% 
[12]     0   0.0% 
[13]     2   0.0% 
[14]     2   0.0% 
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 7 seconds)
```

---

I'm trying to figure out how to calculate the percent of the 2nd column to the third.

Here is what I have, but I know I need to do something else.

I would rather stray from using that hashmap and just use a more correct problem.

---

```
 for (int i = minRoll; i < maxRoll; i++) {
            int dicer = sumArray[i];
            double percent = dicer/numRol;
            System.out.printf("[%d] \t %d \t %.1f%% \n", i , sumArray[i], percent);

        }
```

---

Ninja Edit: Here is the rest of my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author joe
 */
public class DiceSimulator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);



        System.out.print("How many dice do you want to roll: ");
        int amountOfDie = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("");
        //declare diceArray

        Die[] diceArray = new Die[amountOfDie];

        //create a new Die for each reference

        int maxRoll = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < diceArray.length; i++) {

            System.out.print("How many sides on die number " + (i + 1) + ""
                    + ": ");
            int numSides = input.nextInt();
            diceArray[i] = new Die(numSides);
            int minRoll = amountOfDie;
            maxRoll += numSides;

        }
        int minRoll = amountOfDie;

        // int[] sumArray = new int[maxRoll + 1];//to store sum

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.print("How many times do you want to roll: ");
        int numRol = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("\nResults");

        int[] sumArray = new int[maxRoll + 1];

        for (int i = 0; i < numRol; i++) {
            int sum = 0;
            for (Die d : diceArray) {
                int roll = d.roll();
                sum += roll;

            }
           sumArray[sum]++;           
           }

        System.out.println("");

        for (int i = minRoll; i < maxRoll; i++) {
            int dicer = sumArray[i];
            double percent = (dicer/numRol)*100;
            System.out.printf("[%d] \t %d \t %.1f%% \n", i , sumArray[i], percent);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using integer arithmetics, which means that your result gets converted to an `int` before being saved in the `percent` variable.
To avoid this, just cast one of the variables like this:

```
double percent = (double)dicer / numRol;
```

As @PaulHicks says, you really should multiply by `100`. You can do it like this, by declaring it as a floating point literal (`100.0`), to avoid casting altogether:

```
double percent = 100.0 * dicer / numRol;
```

Comment: That'll just give the ratio.  To get the percent value, you need to multiply the result by 100.

Comment: @Keppil My 3rd column is still showing zeros. I have edited my post with my full code. Is there something i'm doing wrong?

Comment: @user3023253: Try my second suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
double percent = dicer/numRol;
```

to

```
double percent = ((double)dicer/numRol)*100;
```

Answer (score 0):

dicer/numRol will always return 0 since dicer and numRol are integers, and numRol > dicer!

To get a percentage result, you have to change the type of dicer to double instead of int

replace:

```
int dicer = sumArray[i];
```

with:

```
double dicer = sumArray[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could increase accuracy by staying away from floating point maths:

```
int percentX10 = (1000 * dicer) / numRol;
String percentString = String.format("%d.%d", percentX10 / 10, percentX10 % 10);
```

Comment: But that's a bit trivial :)